# Swift Range Slider Appear Exactly Like UISlider

Tags: ios, uislider

I am a relatively experienced Swift developer and I have spend the past 3 hours trying to implement a range slider for an app. I have tried about 10 different github accounts including

```
https://github.com/BrianCorbin/SwiftRangeSlider/
https://github.com/brightec/JMMarkSlider/tree/master/JMMarkSlider
https://github.com/warchimede/RangeSlider
https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider
https://github.com/warchimede/RangeSlider/blob/master/RangeSlider/RangeSlider.swift
```

And they all suck. But more importantly, they all fail to **appear like the UISLider**! And hence in my desperate attempt to do something so programmatically simple I come to stack overflow to ask the following.

How can I get the thumb of the slider to appear like the thumb of the UISlider. "Well why don't you get the image of the thumb of the UISlider". 
 **Where do I find this image??** **Where do I find the radius/diameter of the UISlider Thumb??** **How do I get the default track of the UISlider?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, [WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider](https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider), is a very good UISlider alternative. You can customize it at will. 
The customizable properties are listed and you even have a detailed example here on how to subclass it [here](https://github.com/WorldDownTown/RangeSeekSlider/blob/master/Demo/RangeSeekSliderDemo/CustomRangeSeekSlider.swift).